# Dividing two int variables in python

Tags: python, int

I am learning python and here is a piece of code:

```
x = raw_input('Enter a numerator:')
y = raw_input('Enter a denominator:')
print x / y
```

This gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 3, in <module>
    print x / y
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: The error clearly says: You cannot divide two strings. Convert to int before!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to:

```
x = float(raw_input('Enter a numerator:'))
y = float(raw_input('Enter a denominator:'))
```

`raw_input` only returns strings - you need to explicitly convert the result into a numeric - in this case `float`, but you could also use `int` or `decimal.Decimal` for instance.